# PHP: Why are these public initialized variables undefined?

Tags: php, rest, api

I'm trying to fetch from my database some data to display as JSON files, when I try to assign the values I fetch I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\wamp64\www\wsTest\usuario\read.php on line 24

This is the user class:

```
<?php

Class Usuario{
private $conn;
private $tabla="usuario";

public $id;
public $nombre;
public $fecha;

public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn=$db;
    $this->id="";
    $this->nombre="";
    $this->fecha="";
}
//this is my attempt of initializing the variables

// read products
function read(){
    // select all query
    $query = "SELECT (usrNombre) FROM usuario";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
}
```

Here Is the usuario/read.php file, which is the one I'm running

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include_once '../config/connect.php';
include_once '../objects/usuario.php';
//i include usuario.php 

$database = new Database();
//database class defined in config/connect.php
$db=$database->getConnection();

$Usuario=new Usuario($db);
//Here I initialize the user class from /objects/usuario.php
$stmt = $Usuario->read();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0){
    $listaUsrs=array();
    $listaUsrs["registros"]=array();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);

        $usuario_item=array(
        "usrId" => $id, 
        //"usrNombre"=> $nombre,
        //!empty($_POST['usrNombre']) ? $_POST['usrNombre '] : ''/*"usrNombre"*/ => $nombre,
        //"usrFecha" => $fecha,
    );

    array_push($listaUsrs["registros"], $usuario_item);
}

echo json_encode($listaUsrs);
}

else{
echo json_encode(
    array("message" => "No usrs found.")
);
}
?>
```

Does the method not know that it's supposed to use the variables defined in the Usuario object or I didn't initialize it properly?

**EDIT:**
I found that my problem is that $id is undefined in `$usuario_item=array("usrId" => $id, ...` because I had to switch it up, $id had to be $usrId and "usrId" had to be just "id", $usrId refers to the column in my database and "id" refers to the variable in the Usuario Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `public` makes an object property accessible for the public. It does not magically make that property part of the global namespace somehow.

`$this->id` refers to the property `id` *inside* an instance of type `Usuario`. That means you need to refer to it as `$Usuario->id` in that line.

Common practice however would be to define "getters" for such properties and keep them private, so `$Usuario->getId()`. That keeps your internal implementation hidden from the outside world which is one of the purposes of OOP:

```
<?php
Class Usuario {
    // ...
    private $id;
    // ...

    public getId() { return $this->id; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hello, I realized this problem was because I tried to initialize Usuario's variables but that was not needed, I discovered my problem lies when I try to set the new usuario in the array with the values I fetched in

   `$usuario_item=array(
            "usrId" => $id, `. $id seems to be undefined, can you help me solve this?

Comment: So what does ``$row`` contain then?

Comment: `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` I guess each row from the result of the query, I know It fetches correctly beacuse I get the undefined variable error for as many records I have on my database. Notice I did extract($row) which I think it' just to make the code tidier (not sure tho)

Comment: What do yo mean you "guess". Check it! If you get those errors after applying the ``extract()`` function to it (which is a bad habit, by the way), then obviously that array does _not_ contain what you expect it does.

Comment: how do I do so? How do I debug php?

Comment: There are debuggers for php, but you would need to setup some stuff first which is not trivial because of the client server architecture. For this, though, it is absolutely sufficient if you simply output the data using a ``print_r($row)``, better even if you write such debugging data into some log file, you can use php's error log for that. You will find lots of examples for this online. You need to learn that anyway, how else do you expect to be able to develop?

Comment: I did print it and I get the proper results, yet I still get an error when I try to load it to the array of objects' variables

Comment: Please add that data to the question itself, the dumped runtime data.

Comment: I realized I had the sides of the => switched up! the tutorial I used had the same name for both the variable and the database column! thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the public id property on the Usuario object you created, do this:

```
$Usuario->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

With public variable, you can use (new MyClass)->variableName.
With static public variable, use MyClass::variableName.
With protected variable, use getter function as (new MyClass)->getVariableName();
Read document: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php